# How can I extract this substring with a regexp?

Tags: regex, go

I want to extract the number (which could be any nonnegative integer) that comes after "cache", but not the one that comes after "total_cache". I need to be able to do this in a single regular expression, and I can't use lookahead or lookbehind. (I'm doing this in go, which appears to be largely compatible with the tester here: http://regexpal.com/)

---

```
cache 5764452352
rss 2929250304
rss_huge 0
mapped_file 283906048
pgpgin 19709097
pgpgout 17586611
pgfault 39612525
pgmajfault 3757
inactive_anon 160579584
active_anon 3931484160
inactive_file 3560427520
active_file 1040818176
unevictable 49152
hierarchical_memory_limit 9223372036854775807
total_cache 5764452352
total_rss 2929250304
total_rss_huge 0
total_mapped_file 283906048
total_pgpgin 19709097
total_pgpgout 17586611
total_pgfault 39612525
total_pgmajfault 3757
total_inactive_anon 160579584
total_active_anon 3931484160
total_inactive_file 3560427520
total_active_file 1040818176
total_unevictable 49152
```

Comment: That extracts "cache 5764452352", not just the number.

Comment: Its not important what comes after `cache`, its what comes before cache. And its important to know the capabilities of the engine you are using. Your question boils down to this requirement: `(?<!total_)cache (\d+)` This matches anything other than total_cache <number>

Comment: So you would argue that I cannot perform this with a single regex in go (which has no lookbehind)?

Comment: Sort of. You seem to have to match something before cache, but thats a lot of stuff you can match (other than total_), but you have to specify what. Some here on SO, trivialize it away with anchors `^`, but its way too restrictive.

Comment: Also, for reference, go should allow capture groups. The data you are interrested in will be in the capture group. Since there is no lookahead/behinds as you say, there is no way to qualify integer digits in a match without specifying surrounding qualifying references (text). And indeed, this is only done by lookarounds which you don't have anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use FindStringSubmatch and then extract m[1].

http://play.golang.org/p/zOixuvDWsi

Comment: It's unlikely that you will get a better answer than this. Russ wrote Go's new regexp package.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
^cache\s(\d+)
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/jS6sF6

In the Go programming language, I think you can force multi-line mode by using: `(?m)`
Like so:

```
(?m)^cache\s(\d+)
```

**Note:** Im not familiar with Go syntax, so please forgive me is this is wrong, but the regex is correct, it just needs to be used with the multi-line flag.

Comment: That works on your example page, but doesn't appear to work with go (matches "cache 5764452352").

Comment: When I try it on regexpal, it gives me the same match even with multiline mode on.

Comment: Yes, it matches "cache 5764452352" but it only captures "5764452352". So then you just need to access the captured group.  I'm not familiar with go language, on how to access captured groups,..  here let me try to look it up.

Comment: So in go language, I think this: `var match = regexp.MustCompile("(?m)^cache\s(\d+)")` - And then the value you want would be in the variable `match[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
^cache[ ](\d+)$
```

with multi-line(m) flag (In Regex Tester tick the option - ^$ match at line breaks)

Comment: That does not appear to work, at least where I've tested it. Matches nothing.

Comment: I tried it in Regex Tester(with the "^$ match at line breaks" tickbox ticked) and it seemed to work.

Comment: You need to set the "m" flag for this regex to work.

Comment: My bad, I should have read your comment more carefully. It does match "cache 5764452352", but I want it to match only "5764452352".

Comment: Check the edit. I have used a capturing group for the number part. Although it will match the whole thing, there will be a sub-pattern match as well from where you can obtain the number